# Simple Find and Replace with Visual Studio Regular Expression

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

If I have the following code:

```
IObjectSet<AnalystLinkingXREF> AnalystLinkingXREFs { get; }
IObjectSet<Config> Configs { get; }
IObjectSet<ImportProfile_Column> ImportProfile_Column { get; }
```

How would I do a search and replace, to replace `IObjectSet< ANYTHING >` with `result.`

I've tried lots of things in the find box, most recently `IObjectSet<{.+}>` but nothing works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the angle brackets. (They're special characters for beginning and end of word.) This seems to work.

```
IObjectSet\<{.+}\>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
IObjectSet\<{.+}\>
```

However, in the case that the generic parameter is also generic (e.g. `IObjectSet<SomeGenericType<int>>`), you're going to run into trouble.